# Set multiple timeouts from for loop javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to set 8 timeouts from a for loop. i have jquery ids: ir1,ir2...,ir8. Why is the following not working:

```
        var i = 1;
        for (i; i<9; i++ ){
            setTimeout( $('#ir'+i).hide(),100*i);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsbin.com/OrUVoRi/1/edit

```
  var i = 0, elements = [];
  //save jquery calls for performance reasons
  for (i = 0; i<9; i++){
    elements[i] = $('#ir'+i);  
  }
  //you can make this function custom
  var hide = function(i){
    elements[i].hide();
  };
  //the callback loop
  for (i = 0; i<9; i++){
    //bind i value to the hide function
    setTimeout( hide.bind(this, i), 1000*i );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You question is blurred : I'll explain :

in first glance you're having a closure problem :

solution :

```
 var i = 1;
    for (i; i<9; i++){
        (function(a){
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('#ir'+a).hide();
            },1000*a);
        })(i);
    }
```

Also , since all your timeouts execute in burst -you added an increased delay : `100*i`;

Among other solutions  - here is mine :  http://jsbin.com/EpaceSaJ/5/edit

the difference is that in your case - the functions will be at exact 100*i regardless the execution of inner code
While - in my solution : the timeout will be start after each end of last operation.

```
(function g(i,max){

   setTimeout(function   ( )
   {
       console.log(i); // <-- put your stuff here
      if (i==max) return false;
       g((++i),max);
   }, 1000); 
})(1,3); // <--loop  values from 1 to 3 (9 at your case)
```

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout()` should be

```
setTimeout(function(){
   $('#ir'+i).hide()
},100*i);
```

updated.

as @royi namir mentioned, the issue is because of closure(scope) , call a self invoking function , pass i as argument , increased the timeout value to 1000 ... just as an example

```
  var i = 1;
    for (i; i<9; i++){
        (function(a){
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('#ir'+a).hide();
            },1000*a);
        })(i);
    }
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/T6fM9/)

Comment: not working. Neither does:             
                setTimeout(function(i){
                    $('#ir'+i).hide()
                }(i),1000*i);